# java code to catch mqrc 2009 and 2059 errors

Tags: java, ibm-mq

On my below code `connect()` method is able to catch the 2009 and 2059 exceptions. But when I make my queue manager or connection down to generate 2009 or 2059 MQ exception in `getMessage()` method , program is getting hung or it didn't throws it . 
It is waiting in line `queue.get(retrievedMessage, getOptions);`.

Do we need to add additional open option to make the code aware if a connection or queue manager is broken ?

```
Connect()
{
```

MQEnvironment.hostname = hostName;
MQEnvironment.channel = channelName;
MQEnvironment.port = portName;
        try
        {
        qMgr = new MQQueueManager(EvtqManager); // define a queue manager object
        LOGGER.debug("Queue Manager " +EvtqManager+ " Instance Initialized");
        int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING+ MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED;
        queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions, null,null,null); 
        LOGGER.debug("IBM MQQueue:"+queueName+" is accessed");
        getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        getOptions.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT;
        getMessage();
        }
        catch(){
                    if(MQex.reasonCode==2009 || MQex.reasonCode==2059){
             shutDown();
             Connect();
        }
}

getMessage(){
    MQMessage retrievedMessage; 
    while (true) {
               try {
                retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                queue.get(retrievedMessage, getOptions);
                PCFMessage pcfMessage = new PCFMessage(retrievedMessage);
               }
              catch (MQException MQex) {
                if(MQex.reasonCode==2009 || MQex.reasonCode==2059){
                shutDown();
                Connect();
              }
             }
    }

`

Comment: @Vignesh: I am also looking for a solution which should hel me to know whether the queue is down for maintainance or any other problem while making connection.Our queues are also on mainframe.Please advise!!!

Answer (score 1):

No additional options are required. If a MQ method call is in progress and a connection to a queue manager breaks, then the method will return with reason code 2009 or other connection error related reason codes. The reason codes returned will depend on how the connection was broken, for example MQRC_Q_MGR_QUIESCING/MQRC_Q_QMGR_STOPPING will be returned if queue manager is being shutdown.

The hang could be due to the time taken to detect a socket failure. So you may want to check how long does the call wait.

MQRC 2059 is returned when connecting to queue manager but not while receiving messages. So you can remove the check for 2059.

I am just puzzled a bit on your code. You have calls to `shutdown()` and `Connect()` inside `Connect` and `getMessage` methods. Don't you think this leads to recursion?

Comment: Thanks Shashi.Please ignore the recursive calls on Connect() and shutdown(),I've only part of my code here.. Actually I 'm disconnecting and reconnecting my PC from network to test my reconnect logic. Reconnect is working in other part of my code but it gets hung only on "queue.get(retrievedMessage, getOptions);". You are right, but it is waiting indefinitely and it never throws exception at this point. How to make it aware of connection broken or queue manager down?

Comment: No, you don't need to anything extra. Connection broken errors should be automatically thrown. Are you testing by pulling the network cable or ending the queue manager by running endmqm? Also what version of MQ are using? What is puzzling me is, you are using MQGMO_NO_WAIT, so the call should immediately return if there are messages or not.

Comment: I'm testing it by turning off network. I'm connecting to a MQv7 Queue Manager. Yes I have "MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT" option set and I'm handling mqrc 2033 in my catch block but not included here.

Comment: Not quite sure what's going on in your case. You can also write a small sample application that does a socket read from a remote server. When application is waiting on the socket, you turn of the network and see what happens. BTW your queue manager is on the same system or running on a different system?

Comment: Queue manager runs on a different system , it is on mainframe.